# EKS module upgrade requires eks managed node groups be replaced. Will they roll gracefully?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

Using this module to set up eks https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks & upgrading from v17.x to v18.x changes the way names are created for the eks managed node groups. This results in all of the node groups being marked for replacement. When terraform replaces these node groups, will it do so gracefully, by standing up the new node groups first, then draining all the nodes, and finally removing the old nodes?

Note that setting prefix_separator="" as mentioned in the upgrade doc here https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/docs/UPGRADE-18.0.md doesn't prevent the name change, as the name_prefix hardcodes the separator here: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/85e5cae702bafcb81e7e74ec1497cda772de4b86/modules/eks-managed-node-group/main.tf#L49 .